# Selecting one column from a table that has 100 columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with 100 columns (yes, code smell and arguably a potentially less optimized design). The table has an 'id' as PK. No other column is indexed.

So, if I fire a query like:

```
SELECT first_name from EMP where id = 10
```

Will SQL Server (or any other RDBMS) have to load the entire row (all columns) in memory and then return only the first_name?

(In other words - the page that contains the row id = 10 if it isn't in the memory already)

I think the answer is yes! unless it has column markers within a row. I understand there might be optimization techniques, but is it a default behavior?

[EDIT]

After reading some of your comments, I realized I asked an XY question unintentionally. Basically, we have tables with 100s of millions of rows with 100 columns each and receive all sorts of SELECT queries on them. The WHERE clause also changes but no incoming request needs all columns. Many of those cell values are also NULL.

So, I was thinking of exploring a column-oriented database to achieve better compression and faster retrieval. My understanding is that column-oriented databases will load only the requested columns. Yes! Compression will help too to save space and hopefully performance as well.

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: Different RDBMS will approach this differently...

Comment: But probably the answer is it depends on what indexes are available.

Comment: For SQL Server the rows are stored in 8KB pages. This is the unit held in memory - it doesn't read individual bytes from disc on demand. I assume your PK is clustered so you just have a single (clustered) index. In that case the data pages for this index are the only copy of the data (this is the table) and rows on it will contain at least something for each of the 100 columns in the table. It might just be a pointer to the actual data in the event that this is stored off row (LOB data or row overflow) If you  index just `first_name` it would be able to store many more leaf entries per page.

Comment: For columnstore index of course things are different but that isn't what you describe!

Comment: This is a good question. But you should ask it on DBA site-these people are passing exams for their certs after learning these details. From what I know, whenever `where` clause is used, it is executed 1st, whether via index or a full table scan. And it takes the engine to the entire row. At that point, it knows what columns to load into memory. How DB engines do it, each RDBMS differently. Moreover, DBs using different caching mechanisms, to cache both, the compiled SQL and pages of data. Since data sits in blocks or pages in different RDBMSs I would imagine that the entire block is read.

Comment: You can use sql server profiler to trace the query and see that if you execute exactly same query multiple times, the first time it is slower that next times. Because first time RDBMS compiles the query and caches everything. Consequent executions come with savings from caching.

Comment: It won't take the engine to the entire row if the Index contains all the data that is required by the query...

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags, as they have yet to be corrected. You'll still need to [edit] your question to (re)tag the product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:  Indexes and data are stored in "blocks" of 16KB.  Each level of the B+Tree holding the `PRIMARY KEY` in your case needs to be accessed.  For example a million rows, that is 3 blocks.  Within the leaf block, there are probably dozens of rows, with all their columns (unless a column is "too big"; but that is a different discussion).

For MariaDB's Columnstore:  The contents of one columns for 64K rows is held in a packed, compressed structure that varies in size and structure.  Before getting to that, the clump of 64K rows must be located.  After getting it, it must be unpacked.

In both cases, the structure of the data on disk is a compromises between speed and space for both simple and complex queries.

Your simple query is easy and efficient to doing a regular RDBMS, but messier to do in a Columnstore.  Columnstore is a niche market in which your query is abnormal.

Be aware that fetching blocks are typically the slowest part of performing the query, especially when I/O is required.  There is a cache of blocks in RAM.